# Proof Involving Connected Components of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, induction

I have the following problem: prove that every graph with $n$ vertices and $n-k$ edges has at least $k$ connected components.  I have approached this proof using induction, but am having difficulty making progress with the inductive step.  Can someone comment on whether or not this is a good approach?  If so, could you give a suggestion as to how to approach the inductive step?  If not, could you suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: Hint: A forest on $n$ vertices and $k$ components has $n-k$ edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd normally do the induction on the number of edges, so a natural relabeling has the statement changed to: Every graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges has at least $n - k$ connected components.

So we're looking to do the induction on $k$, and the base case for each $n$ would be: A graph with $n$ vertices and $0$ edges has at least $n$ connected components. This should be clear.

For the inductive hypothesis, suppose that a graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges has at least $n-k$ connected components.

Take a graph with $n$ vertices and $k + 1$ edges. Pick any edge and look at the graph without that edge. The reduced graph has $n$ vertices and $k$ edges, and so by the inductive hypothesis, has at least $n - k$ components. Placing the edge back in can reduce the number of components by at most one, meaning the original graph has at least $n - k - 1 = n-(k+1)$ components.

Comment: Is it possible to use induction on the number of vertices, ie. $n+1$ instead of on the edges?

Comment: Sure, take a graph with $n+1$ vertices and $k$ edges. Choose any vertex $v$ and suppose $v$ has degree $d$. Then, removing $v$ leaves the graph with $n$ vertices and $k - d$ edges, which by the inductive hypothesis has at least $n - (k - d) = n - k + d$ connected components. Replacing $v$ can connect at most $d$ of those components into $1$, so the graph has at least $(n+1)-k$ components.